# wordpress - creating sub menu items from functions.php

Tags: wordpress

so I have this functionality in my theme:

Whenever new post in custom post type "people" is created new menu is being created simultaneously with the same name as post's slug. Everything works fine with that BUT.

I need together with the navigation some menu buttons to be created and added at the same tiem. AND this works perfectly well too.

However, my issues start when I am trying to set hierarchy of nav buttons - I have no idea what to set for 'menu-item-parent-id' since every time menu is created for new people posts it has different menu ids, but I want that on all of those menus button "blog" would be child of button "read"

here is a piece of the code that I am using:

```
$menu9 = array(            
        'menu-item-object-id' => 0,
        'menu-item-object' => '',
        'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
        'menu-item-position' => 2,
        'menu-item-type' => 'custom',
        'menu-item-title' => 'read' ,
        'menu-item-url' => '#',
        'menu-item-description' => '',
        'menu-item-attr-title' => '',
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
        );
wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $menu9 );
        $menu2 = array(
        'menu-item-object-id' => 0,
        'menu-item-object' => '',
        'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
        'menu-item-position' => 0,
        'menu-item-type' => 'custom',
        'menu-item-title' => 'blog' ,
        'menu-item-url' => '#',
        'menu-item-description' => '',
        'menu-item-attr-title' => '',
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
        );
wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $menu2 );
```

as you can see i need menu item2($menu2) be child of menu item9 ($menu9)

any help would be much appreciated since I have spent radicilous amount of hours on this...

thanks!

Comment: resolved! will post solution a bit later.